# Performance Monitor unable to connect to machine error

Tags: active-directory, performance-monitoring

I'm trying to set up a machine to run performance logs on my servers. A few of my servers are on a separate domain from the machine and I can't seem to connect to them. No matter what I type into the Run As field I get an error saying "Unable to connect to machine".

The logging machine can ping the servers through DNS so I know there's no connection issues.

Is Performance Monitor able to view machines that are on a separate domain from it?

Comment: Do you have a trust established with the other domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a local account just for performance monitoring on each server and I can now connect Perfmon to the other servers using this account.

I'm not sure why using a domain account wouldn't work but it may have something to do with our environment. We have a Novell and Windows Server environment that has caused similar problems in the past.